# Nest ElasticClient with multiple indexes to index a document

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

At first I had 1 index and my elasticclient was setup like below in my startup.cs

```
public static IServiceCollection AddElasticClient(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var elasticSettings = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IOptions<ElasticSettings>>().Value;

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(elasticSettings.Uri));
    settings
        .ThrowExceptions(elasticSettings.ThrowExceptions)
        .PrettyJson(elasticSettings.PrettyJson)
        .DefaultIndex(elasticSettings.Index)
        .BasicAuthentication(elasticSettings.Username, elasticSettings.Password)
        .DefaultMappingFor<CorrelationContext>(ms => ms.Ignore(p => p.DgpHeader));

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(client);

    return services;
}
```

My writer looks like

```
public class ElasticWriter : IElasticWriter
{
    private readonly IElasticClient _elasticClient;

    public ElasticWriter(IElasticClient elasticClient)
    {
        _elasticClient = elasticClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elasticClient));
    }

    public void Write(AuditElasticDoc doc)
    {
        var indexResponse = _elasticClient.IndexDocument(doc);

        if (!indexResponse.IsValid)
        {
                throw indexResponse.OriginalException ?? new Exception("Invalid Elastic response when writing document.");
        }
    }

}
```

Now there is a new requirement by which they can provide the name of the index to write to.
All authentication data of the different indexes are provided through config settings, so I have everything available at startup.
The document type is always the same.

I found examples of specifying the index when querying but not when indexing.

Can I provide multiple indexes in my ElasticClient and specify the index when executing the IndexDocument?
Or do I need a separate client for each index?

If the latter, is there a way I can still use DI to inject the client in my writer or do I have to create one there at the spot?

Thx.

I'm using Nest 7.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `IndexDocument`, you can use `IndexAsync` method which will allow you to control additional request parameters

```
var indexResponse = await _elasticClient.IndexAsync(doc, descriptor => descriptor.Index("other"));
```

`IndexDocument` is a wrapper method, hiding the complexity of indexing documents from the clients. [Have a look](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/7.9/src/Nest/Document/Single/Index/ElasticClient-Index.cs#L38).

Request auth configuration

```
var indexResponse = await _elasticClient.IndexAsync(doc, 
    descriptor => descriptor
        .Index("other")
        .RequestConfiguration(rq => rq.BasicAuthentication("user", "pass")));
```

Comment: I need to provide credentials for each index (they all differ). But I doesn't seem to be able this way. Or am I missing something else?

Comment: It's possible via `RequestConfiguration`, check my update.

Comment: Great. I'll try it out later today. Priority shift :-(